# I have a web page link that consists few data that needs to be scraped but those data have different id and are considerably to long also

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

How do I scrape those data as they are different from each other?

```
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_0'>Wheat</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_1'>Rice</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_2'>Barleyt</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_3'>Milk</span>
.
.
.

<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_n'>XYZ</span>
```

I need all those data at once.
Help me, prefered language is python.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Why creating any post when you don't know what to do when you get answers in favor of that @Avinash Singh?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using HTMLParser and regex

Give this a try.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import re

html_to_parse = """<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_0'>Wheat</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_1'>Rice</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_2'>Barleyt</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_3'>Milk</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_n'>XYZ</span>"""

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.handle_next = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if re.search('^DataListTicker_lblTicker_[0-9]*$', dict(attrs).get("id","")):
            self.handle_next = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.handle_next :
            print(data)
            self.handle_next = False

ps = MyHTMLParser()
ps.feed(html_to_parse)
```

There is probably a much more elegant way to do this, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach The ID's are different yet they have lots of similarities between them. This is how you can fetch the data out of them:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

element = """
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_0'>Wheat</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_1'>Rice</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_2'>Barleyt</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_3'>Milk</span>
<span id ='DataListTicker_lblTicker_n'>XYZ</span>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(element,"lxml")
for items in soup.select("[id^='DataListTicker_lblTicker_']"):
    print(items.text)
```

Output:

```
Wheat
Rice
Barleyt
Milk
XYZ
```